# How to let anyone upload files into my Dropbox or Google Drive folder using Flask?

Tags: python, flask, google-drive-api, dropbox-api

I need users to be able to upload a file through my Flask-web app using the form, where **my** Dropbox or GDrive is used as a storage. Meaning, users don't have to log in, the storage should be authorised already on my end.

I can't wrap my head around the documentation. Does anyone have any experience with such file handling?

Answer (score 0):

Google has [a page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) which provides a Python example of using the Google Drive API to access your account's cloud storage. It shows how to list files, but you can also use the Drive API to [upload files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#simple):

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

In this case, you would [use an upload form](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/) to send the file to Flask and then on to Google Drive. This is fine if the files are small and the number of users few, but in general this approach will be unscalable since your Flask instance is single-threaded and will not be able to answer other requests while one user is uploading content. If you need the uploading to scale, then you should upload the files directly. You could also investigate doing the task as a background job, via something like Redis Queue (here's a link for [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq)) or Cucumber, which will depend on which platform you're using.

If you don't mind using Amazon's S3 competitor to GDrive and Dropbox, there is a [helpful YouTube series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rmpSPEzgVp4) taking you through setting it up on Flask using the boto3 library. Once you have an S3 bucket and account keys, you can send and receive data as needed. Here is [a Heroku page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python) discussing setting up direct S3 uploads in Python. The details will likely change if you are using another platform.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API was designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files. It is technically possible to connect to just one account. The SDKs don't offer explicit support for it and we don't recommend doing so, for various technical and security reasons.

However if you did go this route, instead of kicking off [the authorization flow](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide), you would embed an existing access token for your own account and app. You could use that to [upload files](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload).